# Clicking a <li> element with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension and one of the features is to click on one of the items in the list code below.

```
<ul class="js-tweet-actions tweet-actions full-width ">
<li class="tweet-action-item pull-left margin-r--13 "> <a class="tweet-action " href="#" rel="retweet"> <i class="js-icon-retweet icon icon-retweet icon-retweet-toggle txt-center"></i> <span class="is-vishidden">Retweet</span> </a> </li>
<li class="tweet-action-item pull-left margin-r--13 margin-l--1"> <a class="js-show-tip tweet-action position-rel" href="#" rel="favorite" title="" data-original-title="  Like from ILoveTomFan   "> <i class="js-icon-favorite icon icon-favorite icon-favorite-toggle txt-center"></i> <span class="is-vishidden"> Like </span> </a> </li>
</ul>
```

How would I mimic a browser click on these elements, the code below is what I tried and it has no effect at all, it doesnt correctly click the element that is being displayed. 
I have tried;

```
document.getElementsByClassName("js-show-tip tweet-action position-rel").click;
document.getElementsByClassName("tweet-action-item pull-left margin-r--13 margin-l--1").click;
document.getElementsByClassName("js-icon-favorite icon icon-favorite icon-favorite-toggle txt-center").click;
var test = x[y].querySelectorAll("li");
     test[2].click;
```

Thanks @Zevee specially the code that made this work was

```
x[y].querySelector('.js-show-tip.tweet-action.position-rel').click();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I couldn't use my stock "Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [MCVE]." for you, so take an upvote!

Comment: I think you need to replace 'getElement"s"` with `getElementByClassName`. If you intentionally tried to use Array of elements try accessing the elements by corresponding index.

Comment: @SwadhikarC `document.getElementByClassName` is not a thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first three don't work because there is an array of elements and because classname only takes one class (iirc)

Try `document.querySelector(<here, put every single class that you want to select seperated by dots (in a string)>).click()`

Note that this selects the first element with all of those classes (iirc)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @zevee same problem as before it defiently selects the correct element however the click on it still does nothing, the website doesnt register a change of state like it would if you did it manually. :( not sure what else to try :/

Comment: oh lol I forgot something - you have to do `()` because click is a method (like so - `elementblahblah.click()`). Updated answer

Comment: There we go! i dont usually code with javascript i was getting errors when i intially started trying to do the '.click()' so i removed the () and it wasnt giving me errors any more! the code that made it work was 'document.querySelector('.js-show-tip.tweet-action.position-rel').click();'